# get char input, check if it is valid or not, if it is invalid clear whole input

Tags: c++, loops, char

my program gets input in char. then checks the input is valid or not

-if input not 'a' or 'b' or 'c', clear whole entered input then get input again (and any input longer than one character is invalid even if starts or includes a or b or c character)

example: ab, ac, cb, abc are invalid. xa, habc are invalid

so my problem is: in example: if i enter input like abcdef or 123456 (input has 6 character in this example) loop turns 6 times and prints "Error! Invalid value. Try again" 6 times. but it must print "Error! Invalid value. Try again" only one time for any input longer than 1 character. i think it checks the input is valid or not first for a then b,c,d,e and f, seperately. so it should clear the whole input if the input is invalid then get input again. how can i clear the whole input if it is invalid. here is my code

```
for(bool isTypeValid=false; isTypeValid==false;){
        cout<<"type: ";
        cin>>type;

        switch(type){
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
                isTypeValid=true;
                break;
            default:
                isTypeValid=false;
                cout<<"Error! Invalid type. Try again.";
                break;}
    }
int number:
cout<<"number: ";
cin>>number;

.............
```

edit: i need to use only iostream header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program receives input line by line. You can just read the entire line with `std::getline` or `std::istream::getline` and inspect the first character.

Comment: i forgot the mention. i need to use only iostream header

Comment: Both `operator<<` and `getline` are in the `istream` header.

Comment: @sinyorcem are you not allowed to use the `string` header either?

Comment: yes i can use only iostream header . and iostream didn't recognized getline

Comment: @sinyorcem You can use this version: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ .

Comment: i cant store input as "type[x]" char array because "type" is char array in outer for loop for other purpose

Comment: @sinyorcem Well you have to figure out what an array is then. You can declare a small array on the stack as in `char text[512];` then call readline, then get the first character.